# Testing a Object Array structure with TypeScript and Jasmine

Tags: typescript, angular, jasmine

I finally got around to TTD! Testing is great however I have a problem. I am testing a function that makes a HTTP call and I receive a large JSON object that has a property called `result`. `result` is an object array, it kinda looks like this:

```
{
    itemsPerPage: 2,
    numPages:1,
    offset:0,
    actualPage:1,
    firstPostingOnPage:1,
    lastPostingOnPage:2,
    totalNumberOfJobs:2,
    result: [
        {
            jobPostingId:1,
            postingVersionId:1,
            title: 'first job',
            applyOnlineLink: 'some link',
            config: null,
            jobStartDate: 1234567890,
            postingVersionStartDate:1234567890,
            postingVersionEndDate:1234567890
        }
    ]
};
```

`result` can have any length but never zero. I want to test the structure of the objects in result. In my app I have the following test:

```
it('The object array should have an object that contains keys "jobPostingId, postingVersionId, title" ', () => {

                    let result:Observable<any> = sut.getJobs();

                    return result.subscribe((content:any) => {

                        assertThat(content, hasProperty('result',

                            containsInAnyOrder({
                                'jobPostingId': is(number()),
                                'postingVersionId': is(number()),
                                'title': is(string()),
                                'applyOnlineLink': is(string()),
                                'config': is(falsy()),
                                'jobStartDate': is(number()),
                                'postingVersionStartDate': is(number()),
                                'postingVersionEndDate': is(number())
                            })
                        ));
                    });
                });
```

This fails as I get the error

```
Expected: an object with {result: [{"jobPostingId":{},"postingVersionId":{},"title":{},"applyOnlineLink":{},"config":{},"jobStartDate":{},"postingVersionStartDate":{},"postingVersionEndDate":{}}] in any order}
[2]          but: result no item in [{"jobPostingId":1,"postingVersionId":1,"title":"first job","applyOnlineLink":"some link","config":null,"jobStartDate":1234567890,"postingVersionStartDate":1234567890,"postingVersionEndDate":1234567890}, {"jobPostingId":2,"postingVersionId":1,"title":"second job","applyOnlineLink":"some link","config":null,"jobStartDate":1234567890,"postingVersionStartDate":1234567890,"postingVersionEndDate":1234567890}] matches: {"jobPostingId":{},"postingVersionId":{},"title":{},"applyOnlineLink":{},"config":{},"jobStartDate":{},"postingVersionStartDate":{},"postingVersionEndDate":{}}
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong, why does it expect an object after each property in the object from the object array.

Thanks in advance, sorry if I have asked a silly question.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the wrong matchers, etc... this worked...

```
it('The object array should have an object that contains keys "jobPostingId, postingVersionId, title", etc.... ', () => {

                    let result:Observable<any> = sut.getJobs();

                    return result.subscribe((content:any) => {

                        assertThat(content, hasProperty('result',
                            contains(
                                hasProperties({
                                    'jobPostingId': is(number()),
                                    'postingVersionId': is(number()),
                                    'title': is(string()),
                                    'applyOnlineLink': is(string()),
                                    'config': is(null),
                                    'jobStartDate': is(number()),
                                    'postingVersionStartDate': is(number()),
                                    'postingVersionEndDate': is(number())
                                }),
                                hasProperties({
                                    'jobPostingId': is(number()),
                                    'postingVersionId': is(number()),
                                    'title': is(string()),
                                    'applyOnlineLink': is(string()),
                                    'config': is(null),
                                    'jobStartDate': is(number()),
                                    'postingVersionStartDate': is(number()),
                                    'postingVersionEndDate': is(number())
                                })
                            )
                        ));
                    });
                });
```